# Download and save xml file on user local machine

Tags: c#, silverlight

On my application I have a button used to save save an xlm file on specific uri indicated on my code. but I would like to give the user the possibility to save this file where he wants.

page.xaml

page.cs

```
private void Bt_Export_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CIRCUIT _selectedCircuit = (CIRCUIT)Lb_Circuits.SelectedItem;
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

            this.DBContext.SaveXmlFile(_selectedCircuit.CIR_CIRCUIT, _action =>
            {
                if (!_action.HasError)
                {

                }
                busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
            }, null);

        }

//

public void SaveXmlFile(string XMlString)
        {
            XmlDocument XmlCircuit = new XmlDocument();
            XmlCircuit.LoadXml(XMlString);          
            XmlCircuit.Save("C:/Users/izdoudou/Ciruit" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyMMddHHmm") + ".xml");
            string ts= XmlCircuit.BaseURI;
        }
```

Could you tell me if it is possible integrate this functionnality with silverlight, and how can I do it?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FolderBrowserDialog` for the purpose.

```
string foldername=@"C:\Users\izdoudou\Ciruit";    
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if( result == DialogResult.OK )
            {
                folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

            }
```

In your code change

`XmlCircuit.Save("C:/Users/izdoudou/Ciruit" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyMMddHHmm") + ".xml");`

to

`XmlCircuit.Save(foldername +"\\"+ DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyMMddHHmm") + ".xml");`

Hope it helps.